# curl: (2) Failure initializing sftp session: Unable to send SSH_FXP_INIT

Tags: curl, sftp, redhat

I am using `curl` on a Red Hat 5.7 server to download files from various companies.

But one connection gives me the following error (anonymized):

```
curl -v -u 'anonymous:' sftp://sftp.acme.com/
* About to connect() to sftp.acme.com port 22 (#0)
*   Trying x.x.x.x...
* connected
* Connected to sftp.acme.com (x.x.x.x) port 22 (#0)
* SSH MD5 fingerprint: 95febe8759c980cd9526ec2b90....
* SSH host check: 0, key: AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQA....
* SSH authentication methods available: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
* Using ssh public key file /home/lanes/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
* Using ssh private key file /home/lanes/.ssh/id_rsa
* Initialized SSH public key authentication
* Authentication complete
* Failure initializing sftp session: Unable to send SSH_FXP_INIT
* Closing connection #0
curl: (2) Failure initializing sftp session: Unable to send SSH_FXP_INIT
```

`sftp` works fine:

```
sftp anonymous@sftp.acme.com
Connecting to sftp.acme.com...
ACME File Transfer Prod #1
sftp> quit
```

Has anyone ever seen this `SSH_FXP_INIT` error?

---

```
curl --version
curl 7.24.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.24.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8b zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5 libssh2/1.2.2
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz
```

---

Verbose `sftp` output:

```
sftp -v anonymous@sftp.acme.com
Connecting to sftp.acme.com...
OpenSSH_4.3p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to sftp.acme.com [139.149.22.130] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/lanes/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/lanes/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: loaded 2 keys
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version SSHD
debug1: no match: SSHD
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug1: Host 'sftp.acme.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/lanes/.ssh/known_hosts:23
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
UBS File Transfer Prod #2
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/lanes/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you connect to the server with psftp? If so it'd be interesting to see what the PuTTY logs say.

Comment: No. I want to see the full SSH packets. eg. http://www.frostjedi.com/terra/dev/putty.log.txt . PuTTY can log those - OpenSSH cannot.

Comment: I am getting `version 'GLIBC_2.7' not found` when trying to run `psftp`. Unfortunately I cannot do everything I want with my Red Hat as it is a near production environment. Would it be useful to try it from a Windows system or not?

Comment: Yah - try it from Windows. Thanks!

Comment: I think I am too dumb for `psftp`... I used my Windows machine to initialize the connection with the following command: `psftp.exe -v anonymous@sftp.acme.com`. But I am not able to get a more verbose output than `Initialised AES-256 CBC client->server encryption`. But at least I am able to initialize the session... I did not find anything to raise the logging level. Are there any other tools I can use on my Red Hat server?

Comment: So you'll need to first create a session in regular PuTTY and save it. In that session you can select the "Logging" tab and chose "SSH packets". Then connect to that session with psftp.

Comment: Did you get that log through PuTTY or psftp? 'cause it doesn't look like that log even has you logging in. It just does the initial key exchange but no password or public key is sent over.

Comment: Thank you for being so patient with me. Now I have a goog feeling: http://pastebin.com/k2Tsz2fL

Comment: Looks like you actually are connecting with psftp. Like if you tried to get a directory listing you would get it with psftp. If that's the case than I'm at a loss...

Comment: Maybe try phpseclib's SFTP implementation, instead? http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I wrote a python script with pexpect to get around this error. But I'd rather do everything with the same program...